# What does comparing 2 Array mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, node-repl

Inside my node.js REPL I create 4 arrays :
`a = [1,2,3]`, `b=[]`, `c=[4,5]`, `d=null` ( ok `d` is not an array but you get my point)

I compare them directly this way :

```
> b = []
[]
> a > b
true
> b > a
false
> a > c
false
> c > a 
true
> c > b
true
> b > c
false
> d > a
false
> a > d
false
```

What are these expressions actually evaluating?
I see that it's clearly not the length of the arrays. Otherwise `c > a` would have been `false`.

Can somebody please help me understand!

Comment: You need to learn a lot of javascript's implicit conversions (i personally prefer explicit ones, where comparing arrays like that just throws, but it is what it is), and use them one after another.

Comment: The short version is, JavaScript is casting the array to some other type and using that type's comparator for the `operator>` evaluation. Since these results don't have any valuable semantic meaning, it's basically a pointless operation and you should create your own routine for comparing arrays if you need that functionality. There isn't much point in further stressing *why* JavaScript chooses to implement things this way, as there are many other examples of weird JavaScript behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrays get converted to strings first (including the commas).

`[1, 2, -3]` for instance becomes the string `'1,2,-3'`

Then the strings get compared in an "alphabetical" order (based on their character codes).

It is not a very intuitive way of accomplishing comparisons, and should be avoided.